# Mifare Desfire EV1 Authentication

Tags: authentication, mifare

```
-> 5AF4013D
<- 00 /*Success*/
-> AA01
<- AFA8394ED57A5E83106B4EE72FD2BB0CC4
```

How to proceed from here?

I have been struggling about a week with this. I can select app from the card and get that first response with the 0xAA ("AFA8394ED57A5E83106B4EE72FD2BB0CC4" equivalent) but what to do after that?

Do i need to encrypt or decrypt the response with my App_auth_key (16bit) or what and then send it to the card?

Encryption which I use is AES.

Comment: Could you clarify what you are actually asking? Your communication example suggests that you want to know why the card responds with `0xAF` in response to the write command, while the questions below suggest that you are struggling with the authentication part.

Comment: Im struggling with the authentication. I just took that part from another thread. Haven't used this StackOverflow before. I just need the code for how to authenticate with the card. I edited the question now.

Comment: In that case you might want to take a look at [libfreefare](https://code.google.com/p/libfreefare/source/browse/libfreefare/mifare_desfire.c)

Comment: It can't be done with default Android libraries?

Comment: It can. Android provides the necessary cryptography API. That link was meant as a example for how you do the authentication (and the later encryption).

Comment: I really don't understand that code. Can you help me? I just need help at authenticating and reading the real tag ID. Only problem I have is the authenticating part. I have a big app and this has been the only problem so far. How to do that authentication in Java code? When I try to encrypt the response with the App_auth_key and then sending it to the card the response is "0xAE" which I think means access denied. This is the first time I do anykind of communication with AES encrypted cards.

Comment: Sorry, it's not that easy to help without violating the NDAs with NXP. I assume you did not yet request the DESFire EV1 data sheet from NXP, did you?

Comment: Btw. what do you mean with "real tag ID"?

Comment: The NFC card returns randomID when i read the tag. I need to connect to the app on the card which succeeds. After that I send 0xAA to get that response which starts with AF and 16 bits after that. I need to generate session key with that and App_Auth_Key(16bit) which belongs to that Application on the card and authenticate with the card. Is there any easy way to authenticate with the card? We use non-encrypted and AES encrypted cards in the Android Application. I can read the non-encrypted fine and but I just don't seem to get those encrypted ones working. Not enough skills in AES encryption.

Comment: http://noobstah.blogspot.fi/2013/04/mifare-desfire-ev1-and-android.html I found this example but its not for AES encryption. I need the same kind of code but for AES.

Comment: As I indicated before, a good start would be to request the MIFARE DESFire EV1 data sheet from NXP. That data sheet explains the authentication procedure.

Comment: Got it working! Can't say it was easy but finally did it. Feel like a boss now.