# Mifare DESfire EV1 4k AES Authentication

Tags: authentication, mifare

Has anyone been able to authenticate with this card using this encryption method? I have no clue what to do after selecting the app and starting the authentication. Below is my code. Only copied the relevant parts and used example KEY and SELECT_APP

```
//AUTHENTICATION COMMANDS

    private static final byte[] NATIVE_AUTHENTICATION_KEY = new byte[] {
            (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05,
            (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x09, (byte) 0x0A,
            (byte) 0x0B, (byte) 0x0C, (byte) 0x0D, (byte) 0x0E, (byte) 0x0F,
            (byte) 0x00 };

    private static final byte[] START_AUTHENTICATION_COMMAND = new byte[] {
            (byte) 0xAA, (byte) 0x01 };


    private static byte[] SELECT_APPLICATION = { (byte) 0x5A, (byte) 0x01,
            (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03 };

//AUTHENTICATION FUNCTION

        private void StartAuthentication(Tag tag) {
            try {
                IsoDep.get(tag).connect();
                byte[] response = IsoDep.get(tag)
                        .transceive(SELECT_APPLICATION);

                Log.e("SELECT_APP", ByteArrayToHexString(response));

                byte[] response2 = IsoDep.get(tag).transceive(START_AUTHENTICATION_COMMAND);

                Log.e("START_AUTH", ByteArrayToHexString(response2));

                } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                }

                }
```

SELECT_APP returns 0x00 (OK) and START_AUTH returns 0xAF+(16bit). What to do after getting that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mifare Desfire EV1 Authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20266180/mifare-desfire-ev1-authentication)

Comment: How to authenticate both ways can be read here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26495399/desfire-ev1-internal-authenticate-only

Answer (score 1):

If your answer returns `0xAF` means extra info is pending.
Send `0xAF` till you get `0x00` in retun, `0xAF` means more data in return is pending.